# Java parse String to Int

Tags: java

This is my code to ask the database for all users which I  save later to a txt-file line-by-line. Works good so far except for the String `steamid`.

```
public String getAllUsers() {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Path out = Paths.get("C:\\Teamspeak\\alluserlist.txt");
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, dbUser, dbUserPW);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "select nickname, unique_id, is_admin, steamid, is_banned from users where nickname not like 'Unknown from%'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String nickname = rs.getString("nickname");
            String id = rs.getString("unique_id");
            String admin = rs.getString("is_admin");
            String steamid = String.valueOf(rs.getString(4));
            String banned = rs.getString("is_banned");

            int steamnr = Integer.parseInt(steamid.replaceAll("[\\s|\\u00A0]+", ""));

            //System.out.println(nickname + ":" + id + ":" + admin + ":" + steamid);
            if (!nickname.equals("")) {
                if (Integer.valueOf(banned) == 1) {
                    nickname = "<s>" + nickname + "</s>";
                    id = "banned";

                    // <a href="somepage.html" target=newtab>text</a>

                    arrayList.add(nickname + ";" + id + ";" + admin + ";" + "<a href=\"http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/" + steamnr + "\"target=newtab>go to Steam</a>");
                } else {
                    arrayList.add(nickname + ";" + id + ";" + admin + ";" + "<a href=\"http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/" + steamnr + "\"target=newtab>go to Steam</a>");
                }

            }               
        }
        try {   
            Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
            Files.write(out,arrayList, charset);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "error";
}
```

I tried to remove whitespaces using

```
int steamnr = Integer.parseInt(steamid.replaceAll("[\\s|\\u00A0]+", ""));
```

but it shows no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 7 6 5 6 1 1 9 8 0 5 7 5 9 7 5 3 1"
            at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
            at database.DatabaseHandler.getAllUsers(DatabaseHandler.java:329)
            at main.Main.main(Main.java:139)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

steamid is a varchar in database

[image: dbscreen]

Comment: What is the value of `steamid`? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: A value of the steamid is in the exception : " 7 6 5 6 1 1 9 8 0 5 7 5 9 7 5 3 1"

Comment: The value is to big for int. Try long and Long.parseLong() instead.

Comment: Have you tried `steamid.replace(" ", "");` to do replace without usage of regex? And as Ralf Renz stated even value without spaces is too large for int.

Comment: First of all for that String you need something like `"7 6 8 1".replaceAll("\\s", "").trim()` and after that convert it to `int` but it can be invalid integer. A line that represents a  huge number can be larger than `int` can hold so you better get it as `Long.valueOf(...)`

Comment: Your `replaceAll` call doesn't seem to be working, probably because the characters between the digits are not actually spaces. You should print each character of `steamid` as a hex number (perhaps using your debugger) just to check.

Comment: By the way, your regex doesn't mean what you think it means. The `|` character is taken as a literal character because it's inside `[ ]`, which matches any single character from the set of whatever is contained in the brackets. So you don't want to include `|`. But even `[\\s\\u000A]` doesn't make sense. That matches any "space" character OR the 0A (linefeed) character. But the latter belongs to the set of the former! So `[\\s]` is enough. Then the brackets become redundant: a simple `\\s` will do. (And you don't need `\\s+` with `replaceAll` since it replaces _All_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that even if they are displayed as whitespaces, `\\s` is not removing them, so they may be other characters.

The way to still remove them regardless of them being whitespaces or not, is to remove **all non-digits**, by replacing this:

```
steamid.replaceAll("[\\s|\\u00A0]+", "")
```

with this:

```
steamid.replaceAll("\\D+", "")
```

Also, that number is too big to fit in an `int`, you should use a `long` instead (or a `BigInteger`, as others suggested):

```
long steamnr = Long.parseLong(steamid.replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
```

[Demo here](https://ideone.com/DFc5QE)

Comment: Thank you, it says me java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: @piguy It means that steamid is empty then. You should check that first.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your number is too big for an Integer. Try parsing it as [Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)

```
String steamid = " 7 6 5 6 1 1 9 8 0 5 7 5 9 7 5 3 1";
Long steamnr = Long.parseLong(steamid.replaceAll("[\\s|\\u00A0]+", ""));
System.out.println(steamnr);
```

Comment: Actually that's not the issue here. The error occurs before the conversion to int. If the replace worked, it would have shown `NumberFormatException: for input string "76561198057597531"`. It shows `for input string " 7 6 5 6 1 1 9 8 0 5 7 5 9 7 5 3 1"`, that means that the `replaceAll` is not working.

Comment: We don't know what's coming from OP's database. Maybe these characters are not whitespaces, even if they are displayed as such. What we know for sure is that the `replaceAll` is not working, as the resulting string from the exception still has whitespaces.

Comment: @BackSlash I think the same - I added my DB structure in my post

Answer (score 1):

Even if you remove all blanks (which you don't, as the error message shows), the number is too big to fit into an `Integer` object. So you need to use a data type capable of storing larger values.

I would advice you to use the class `BigInteger` to store such values, as there is likely no guarantee that it won't exceed the range of `Long` as well.